# NoReverseMatch pattern not found in django2

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

NoReverseMatch found for a url i have tried  and
{% url '/feedback/form/' %}

i am using a feedback app.

```
#feedback\urls.py
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import request_feedback

urlpatterns = [
    path('form/', request_feedback, name = 'get_feedback' ),
]



#feedback\views.py
def request_feedback(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        feedback_form = FeedBackForm(request.POST)
        if feedback_form.is_valid():
            feedback_form.save()
            return redirect('')
    else:
        feedback_form = FeedBackForm()
    return render(request, 'feedback/feedbackform.html', {'feedback_form':feedback_form})



#webapp\urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('feedback/', include("feedback.urls")),
    path('user/',include("user.urls")),
]
```

i am getting this error
NoReverseMatch at /feedback/form/

Reverse for '' not found. '' is not a valid view function or pattern name

i am using python 3.7 and django 2

i do mitigate this problem

Comment: <form action="{% url 'get_feedback' %}"  method="POST">

Comment: i got it error is due to empty string redirect